# Python :unit test throws <Response streamed [200 OK]> instead of actual output

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

```
from flask import jsonify

@app.route('/urlinfo/1/<path:URL>', methods=['GET']) 
def search(URL): 
  if something:
     a=dict(message="everything is good"
     resp=jsonify(a)
     return resp
  else:
     a=dict(error="problem")
     return jsonify(a)
```

I am curling it using

```
 curl  http://127.0.0.1:5000/urlinfo/1/'https://www.youtube.com/'
```

and it is returning  desired output in json format.

I wrote a Unittest for it

```
 import unittest

 def test_search_non_malicious_url(self):
    #pass safe URL and test web service does not block it
    new_URL= "183.434.44.44:90"
    expected= {
                  "message": "Everything is good"
             }    
    self.assertEqual("a",search(new_URL))
```

Unittest fails because instead of returning string ("message": "Everything is good"), `search(new_URL)` returns *Response streamed [200 OK]*

How to return output as a dictionary `{"message": "Everything is good"}`?

Comment: You could unindent `return jsonify(a)` since both the if and else lead to that

Answer (score 18):

Figured it out. I had to add `.data` to get the value:

```
self.assertEqual("a",search(new_URL).data)
```